# Nativescript SDK errors

Tags: angular, typescript, android-studio, nativescript

I am creating a nativescript app with angular, I am using a json server.
I have my json server running and when I run 'tns run android' or 'tns doctor' I get these errors.

× The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
 To be able to perform Android build-related operations, set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to point to the root of your Android SDK installation directory.

× WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

× WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
 You will not be able to run your apps in the native emulator. To be able to run apps
in the native Android emulator, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK
and its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

× Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later.
 Run `$ sdkmanager` to manage your Android SDK versions.

× You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=28'.
 Run `$ sdkmanager` from your command-line to install required `Android Build Tools`. In case you already have them installed, make sure `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is set correctly.

× Error executing command 'javac'. Make sure you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
 You will not be able to build your projects for Android.
To be able to build for Android, verify that you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and configured it according to system requirements as
 described in http://docs.nativescript.org/setup/ns-cli-setup/ns-setup-win.html#system-requirements

× WARNING: The Java Development Kit (JDK) is not installed or is not configured properly.
 You will not be able to work with the Android SDK and you might not be able
to perform some Android-related operations. To ensure that you can develop and
test your apps for Android, verify that you have installed the JDK as
described in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html (for JDK 8).

I have installed JDK and android studio, I have installed SDK in android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your environment file (in my case `.zprofile`) and add these:

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/$USER/.android/avd
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/
```

**Make sure that you set your paths to where they're located on your computer as they may not be the same.**

Then run `source .zprofile`, restart your terminal just in case and then try running `tns doctor` again. If you have Android Studio open then restart that as well.

Comment: now when I run tns doctor I get 'tns' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Yes they are corret

Comment: the path for my SDK in android studio is C:\Users\Natasha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk I have set this as my ANDROID_HOME

Comment: I unistalled everything and followed the instructions for preparing the development enviroment added these paths to my environment  file and I dont get the errors anymore

Comment: @user3149979 Nice :)